# How to run Github Desktop on Manjaro

Tags: manjaro, github-desktop, appimage

I am new to Manjaro and Linux in general. I downloaded the AppImage from the github repsitory: https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases/tag/release-2.9.14-linux2 and set the properties to be able to run as program. How can i start Github Desktop from the terminal now? What is the recommended folder to store .AppImage files in my system?

Comment: As for installing, the recommend tool is https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher. Installing this on Manjaro can be done with `sudo pacman -S appimagelauncher` on the command line. Alternatively, it can be downloaded as the`appimagelauncher` package in the graphical package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I enabled AUR download, downloaded the Github Desktop from AUR.
To run the application from the terminal you have to type github-desktop